# how does no conflict work in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
// COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  var old = $.fn.collapse

  $.fn.collapse = function (option) {
   ......
  }

  $.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


  // COLLAPSE NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.collapse.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.collapse = old
    return this
  }
```

This is the code from bootstrap 3 Collapse plugin. I am learning js by readying this plugin code.

I understand the syntax, but I have no idea how the no conflict works? 
Why this way can handle the conflict? 
what does "this" point to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What this does is first assigns the original value of `$.fn.collapse` to a variable, `old`. That way it can keep a reference when overwriting.

In the `$.fn.collapse.noConflict` function, it puts back the original value of `$.fn.collapse`, from the variable `old`. `return this` allows you to set this collapse plugin to a different variable.

`var collapsePlugin = $('*').collapse.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.noConflict will reset the $ variable so it's no longer an alias of jQuery. Aside from just calling it once, there's not much else you really need to do. Though, you can create your own alias with the return value, if you'd like:

```
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();

 // Do something with jQuery
 j( "div p" ).hide();

 // Do something with another library's $()
 $( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```

Comment: why I call "$.noConflict()" 2 times, it returns "TypeError: Cannot call method 'noConflict' of undefined" the 2nd time? I guess I didn't understand it completely. Can you please walk me through this process which resulting an error 2nd time?

Comment: I mean to say by second time that you can use in another script with
       var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
       $( "content" ).style.display = "none";
and in same script you have to use same variable(j) which we have created i.e.
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
         j( "div p" ).hide();